# How to retrieve items from a db and then display one row of data on a different page on button click using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am having a huge problem. I have displayed data on a single events page the events being displayed are the rows of data in the database.
Here's the code.

```
<?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY `startdate` DESC";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<div class='event col-sm-3'>
            <h1>". $row['eventname'] . "</h1>
            <p><b>Regular:</b> " . $row['regular'] . "Ksh</p>
            <p><b>VIP:</b> " . $row['vip'] . "Ksh</p><br>
            <p><b>" . $row['startdate'] . "</b></p>
            <p><b>Tickets remaining:<b>" . $row['tickets'] . "</p><br><br>
            <button class='button'>book</button>
            </div>";
        }
      }
     ?>
```

[Here are the events being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwoTL.png)

Now I would want when I click the button that says book the event the fields(items) in the  specific row that I have clicked(using the book button) be displayed in a different page and get stored in variables.

Comment: What do you mean have a question. That is the question.

Comment: If you're trying to be rude that's not really nice of you. Just because I'm a newbie doesn't mean you have to talk like that.

Comment: Why is it rude to point out that you did not ask any question? You described your requirements, but nothing further than that. Being able to formulate a question has nothing to do with how experienced you are in programming.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you might want to use an 'a' tag and not a button.

You should pass the 'id' value of the ticket to the page where you want to have an independent query (individual_ticket.php)

Your code should look like this

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY `startdate` DESC";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<div class='event col-sm-3'>
        <h1>". $row['eventname'] . "</h1>
        <p><b>Regular:</b> " . $row['regular'] . "Ksh</p>
        <p><b>VIP:</b> " . $row['vip'] . "Ksh</p><br>
        <p><b>" . $row['startdate'] . "</b></p>
        <p><b>Tickets remaining:<b>" . $row['tickets'] . "</p><br><br>
        <a href="individual_ticket.php?id=<?=$row['id']">Book</a>
        </div>";
    }
  }
 ?>
```

And inside the 'individual_ticket.php'.

Do something like.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
  $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,  FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = '$id'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      //you can start assigning variables here
    }
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Bamidele. It worked. You have no idea how much you've saved me. Thumbs up.

Comment: You are always welcomed. A vote up will be nice though.. :) :)